# Access data in runtimeType Response<dynamic> : Dio error

Tags: flutter, dio

I am sending a request which is erroring with dio library

When catching the error, I can `print(e.response);` and `print(e.response.statusCode);`

The runtimeType of the response is `Response<dynamic>`

And when printing the response I get something like this

```
{"message":"there is message from the api here"}
```

I cannot access this message to print it.

I tried

`e.response.message and get` errors.dart:167 `Uncaught (in promise) Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'message'`

`e.response["message"]` and get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]'`

I tried json.encoding the e.response, and it doesn't work either, how can I access the data inside the type `Response<dynamic>`

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried ```e.response.data``` or ```e.message``` ?

Comment: @ikerfah thank you, it worked with print(e.response.data["message"]); I had not added data

Comment: I'll add it as an answer it might be useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.response.data['...']` instead in order to access the data you want,